# Issue with django-pisa pdf in dhivehi language

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, django-views, pisa

I've generated a pdf using Django-pisa.. the PDF content is taken from database which is in the correct alignment  but can't get it done right on the PDF....

I've used:

```
filename = "/home/anoop/DjangoCodes/hello.pdf"
    c = '''<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {font-family: code2000;src: url(dhivehi.otf.ttf);}
    html {font-family: code2000;dir: rtl;unicode-bidi:bidi-override;}
    </style>
    </head><body><div dir='rtl'>%s</div></body></html>''' % content_text
    print c
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(c,file(filename, "wb"))
    if not pdf.err:
        pisa.startViewer(filename)
```

content_text contains the dhivehi text..

Example :  content_text:  އެގޮތުން އައްޑޫގެ މަރަދޫ އާއި މަރަދޫފޭދޫ އާއި ފޭދޫ އަށްވެސް އުދަ އަރާފައިވާ ކަމަށް

```
        text in pdf:  ‫ށަމަކ ާވިއަފާރައ ަދުއ ްސެވްށައ ޫދޭފ ިއާއ ޫދޭފޫދަރަމ ިއާއ ޫދަރަމ ެގޫޑްއައ ްނުތޮގެއ‬
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem and I solved it by just changing the fonts which can display these type of characters (e.g. Arial Unicode MS, DejaVuSerif).

Edit:

I was using mpdf library (unicode support) which is written in PHP for dynamic PDF creation with russian language (Cyrillic) and faced similar problem. At that time I was using arial font and then I switched to ArialUni,DejaVuSerif fonts which solved the problem.

Comment: As it stands your answer is a bit short. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Thank you so much Arialuni fixed my problems :D. I was using Code2000 and it does not work with Japanese text.